# Creating Tricky Update Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, dml

Help!! I am at my wits end!!

I have been attempting to create an update trigger to simply insert values into another table when it is updated.

TBL_PUPILS:

```
Age               smallint
Height            smallint
Weight            smallint
Class             int
SurName           varchar(28)
Sick_Days         smallint
```

The difficulty arises from each pupil being uniquely identified by a concatenation of the first 5 columns.

I have already successfully managed to create the INSERT TRIGGER;

```
CREATE Trigger [dbo].[tr_tbl_Pupils_For_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_Pupils]
FOR INSERT
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Age smallint, @Height smallint, @Weight int, @Class int, @SurName varchar(28), @Sick_Days int

Select @Age = Age, @Height = Height, @Weight = Weight, @Class = Class, @SurName = SurName, @Sick_Days = Sick_Days
From inserted

insert into tbl_Pupil_Detail Values(@Age, @Height, @Weight, @Class, 'New', @SurName, @Sick_Days, GETDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

END
```

The Insert trigger above would be used to capture date time etc when a new pupil joined.

How would create a similar UPDATE TRIGGER when the amount of sick days are amended for existing pupils?

Please let me know if you need more info!!

Comment: Your insert trigger is flawed as it cannot handle multi-row inserts. The insert statement should be `INSERT...SELECT...FROM inserted'. You should have a composite primary key on the 5 columns and, in the update trigger, join inserted and pupil_detail on those 5 columns to identify the rows that need to be updated.

Comment: What if a student gains some weight?  Or grows?

Comment: Or transfered from one class to another?

Comment: I have just used an example table with the exact same table structure. Sick_days is the only column that can be UPDATED

Comment: Aside: If you ever do have a need to write a trigger that can only process exactly one row then it should check the count of rows in `inserted` (or `deleted`) and use `throw` or `RaIsError` to proudly proclaim its limitation.

Answer (score 0):

There are very valid points raised in the comments by @DanGuzman, @GordonLinoff and @ZoharPeled. If the example given is indeed your table structure and you are still designing the system, you need to take a good look at reorganising it or it **will break**, and probably sooner rather than later.  The main problem: **students should never be identified across tables by fields that could change**.

In fact it makes me cringe to answer this for you, but database redesign is a whole other question, so here goes:

```
CREATE Trigger [dbo].[tr_tbl_Pupils_For_Update]
ON [dbo].[tbl_Pupils]
FOR UPDATE
AS   
BEGIN

update d
set d.Sick_Days = i.Sick_Days
from tbl_Pupil_Detail d
inner join inserted i 
  on d.Age = i.Age          -- bad: don't join on fields that could change!
  and d.Height = i.Height   -- bad
  and d.Weight = i.Weight   -- bad
  and d.Class = i.Class     -- bad
  and d.SurName = i.SurName -- bad

END
```

The `inserted` table contains all the updated rows in the `tbl_Pupils` table: notice how I've done an update statement by joining the `inserted` table with the target table(`tbl_Pupil_Detail`)? This will update multiple target rows at once, if there are multiple rows in `tbl_Pupils` updated in one update statement.

This is important for both the INSERT and UPDATE triggers because you never know when someone will try to insert or update records in bulk - loading one row into variables as you've done above will fail.

Comment: Note this also assumes that the 5 linking columns are named the same thing in `tbl_Pupil_Detail`.  You didn't say in your question.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand the table structure is not ideal but it has been inherited and can not be changed.The fields do not change, and the column names I have supplied are only representative of the actual column names

Comment: I understand.  It needed to be pointed out though, in case you were designing this from scratch!  I hope my answer has helped.